# What is 80PLUS?

Tags: power-supply, power

Looking at various power supplies I see some of them listed as 80PLUS with various metal combinations. What does the 80PLUS label represent and how more efficient are they compared to ones without the label?

Comment: There are four answers, but nobody bothered to clarify that this "efficiency" that they're writing about is the **ratio of** the useful electrical **power output** (in DC voltages) **versus** the electrical **power consumed** from the wall outlet (in AC voltage).  The ratio is expressed as a percentage.

Comment: @sawdust so write up a better answer :). I'll upvote and accept the best one.

Comment: I'm lazy, and a lot has already been written.  I previously wrote [this](http://superuser.com/questions/446419/will-a-500w-smps-consume-more-electricity-than-a-250w-smps-if-they-are-powering/446458#446458).  There's a pretty graph [here](http://superuser.com/questions/509516/does-the-wattage-on-a-power-supply-simply-mean-the-max-output-wattage/509524#509524), but unfortunately there's no curve for an uncertified or inefficient PSU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`80 PLUS` simply means that [the power supply is 80% or more efficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_Plus) at various levels of power output relative to its rated maximum. The "metal combinations" signify varying conformance to this target at different fractions of maximum rated power output. Here is a table with the various levels:

[image: 80Plus]

Greater than 80% efficiency means that less than 20% of the power input becomes something other than the desired DC voltage (for example heat). **Efficiency**, simply enough, is the ratio of input power to output useful power (or more generally, useful work performed by a device).

In terms of raw numbers, this means that a power supply rated for 500W output will, under full load, require a maximum of 125W that does not contribute to its useful DC output. According to [AN46 - Efficiency and Power Characteristics of Switching Regulator Circuits](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an46.pdf), switching power supplies (of which PC power supplies of today are a subset) typically range from 70% to 90% efficiency, so >80% gives you a ten percentage point boost over an "inefficient" supply converting 70% of the input power into useful DC. At 500W output, that translates to approximately 90W power saved going from 70% to 80%, although the exact numbers are likely to vary between various PSUs, rated maximum loads and *actual load* at the time of the measurement (switch-mode power supplies have a base load for their internal circuitry, which remains largely or entirely constant regardless of the output power drawn).

Comment: +1 for good explanation - also touching on raw heat output of "inefficient" psu's.

Comment: Not quite.  Not only are you never going to be at 100% load, but even bad power supplies are still 80% efficient at around 75% of their rated load.  In practice, where it matters is down at around 25% of maximum load, which is where your computer is going to spend most of its time when you aren't playing video games or doing other high power activities.  80+ Gold rated supplies will maintain high efficiency even at this low load where silver and bronze drop off in this range.

Comment: *"produce a maximum of 125W of non-useful DC voltage"* -- PSUs don't work that way.  Some of the energy is lost/wasted as heat.  Some of the energy is "lost" in order to power the active circuitry of the switch-mode power supply.  It's this internal power consumption that results in the reduced efficiency as the PSU's output is reduced to low wattages.

Comment: @sawdust I updated the answer to hopefully clarify some of these points.

Comment: You managed to define the reciprocal of efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

80Plus is an energy efficiency certification program. There are different levels of certification depending on how effecient the PSU is: standard, followed by bronze through to platinum (there's also a Titanium grouping for 230V intervals). The ratings are based on how much power is being lost at different loads. The difference between bronze and platinum tends to be around 10% efficiency, with the bronze PSUs running at around 80% typically.

Check out the full list of power supply manufacturers and their certified products [here](http://www.plugloadsolutions.com/80PlusPowerSupplies.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to be a standard for PSU efficiency. There are several sub-levels - for more info see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_Plus)

Generally I would expect an 80PLUS PSU to be more efficient than an "unlabelled" one.

Answer (score 1):

Like Prang said, it's an efficiency standard developed to make sure PSUs don't waste power.

See below from Wikipedia:

> 80 Plus (trademarked 80 PLUS) is a voluntary certification program
>   intended to promote efficient energy use in computer power supply
>   units (PSUs). Launched in 2004 by Ecos Consulting, it certifies
>   products that have more than 80% energy efficiency at 20%, 50% and
>   100% of rated load, and a power factor of 0.9 or greater at 100% load.
>   That is, such PSUs will waste 20% or less electric energy as heat at
>   the specified load levels, thus reducing electricity use and bills
>   compared to less efficient PSUs. Sometimes, rebates are given for
>   manufacturers who use 80 Plus-certified PSUs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_Plus