# Does PSU Wattage Matter

Tags: computer-building, desktop-computer, intel-core-i7

My PC uses Intel Core i7 4790K, Gigabyte GeForce GTX 970, G.Skill 16 GB RipjawsX (DDR3), Intel SSD 120 GB, 1TB Hard Drive, ASUS Z97-C (Motherboard), Corsair Carbide Spec 01 and for the power Corsair CX 750M Power Supply (750 W).

I wanted to know what happens if i get more Wattage then i need will it break, of course if i get less it won't work. So is my Power Supply Efficient For My Build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More [maximum] wattage then you need will not break it. The specs are a maximum what a PSU can deliver, not a fixed value which it must deliver.

I tend to try to use simple real life things to compare with. In this case the PSU is a car which can drive up to 75kmph. It can also drive slower.

Comment: Do u recommend 500 W (Corsair CX 500M)

Comment: I recommend calculating how much is used an buy a PSU which is slightly larger. (When used at 80-95% most PSUs ere most efficient.). Unless you want to add more component later, then get more than calculated for the current setup.

Comment: Aha. Thought I already answered a similar question before: Please see http://superuser.com/questions/509516/does-the-wattage-on-a-power-supply-simply-mean-the-max-output-wattage for more details.

Comment: One More Thing. Do u recommend a motherboard, or is mine okay (Its meant for like CS:GO, Minecraft, Portal)

Comment: I have no experience with those games at all, but based on the rather fast CPU I would be surprised if it could not handle it. That said, such questions are not on topic for [su].